# splitting terms in a polynomial expression without external libraries like sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, polynomials, polynomial-math

Say i inputted `"1+2x+3x^2"` or `"1-2x+3x^2"`

How do i make a function that splits and makes a list of each term like `[1, 2x, 3x^2]` or `[1, -2x, 3x^2]`.
I have been stumped at this for a while, for now the function im using currently, seperates only at the "+" so to get a list like `[1, -2x, 3x^2]` i have to input 
`"1+-2x+3x^2"`

Note: I won't be using complex polynomials but simple looking ones that doesn't include parenthesis or fractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

s = '1+2x^2-3x^-3'

s = re.sub('\^-', 'neg', s) # trick to deal the negative powers
print(s)
s=s.replace('-','+-')
s=s.replace('neg','-')
sub = s.split('+')

print(sub)
```

This will split your negative power variables correctly.

Comment: You could just use a negative lookbehind.

Comment: @MadPhysicist very true.